# How to override bootStrap CSS in case of checkboxes

Tags: css

The checkbox style has been bootstrapped as `input[type="checkbox"]{float:left;margin: 3px 5px 0 0;}`.

Instead of that i want it to be styled as `{margin:0 5px 0 0;*float:left;*display: inline-block;*margin-top:5px;}` without changing the bootstrap,i tried all possible alternatives which i know like `!important` etc.

Comment: You can add another css Like (custom.css) after the bootstrap.css

Comment: Give the checkbox another class, and define the style you want for that class.

Comment: I think its just a matter of adding a new style that should come below the bootstrap css, right?

Comment: Can you show us the full markup beacause `!important` should work if done correctly

Comment: i've already defined class called .auxoDynamicCheckbox{margin:0 5px 0px 0px;*float:left;*display: inline-block;*margin-top:5px;} but the bootstrap is overriding it.

Answer (score 0):

Give the checkbox another class, and define the style you want for that class.

**Example**

```
<div class="custom-checkbox">
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="">Option 1</label>
</div>
```

**CSS Style**

```
.custom-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]{
    margin: 5px 5px 0 0 !important;
    display: inline-block;
}
```